# Open context menu on xamarin forms map

Tags: google-maps, xamarin, xamarin.forms, maps

I am working on map in xamarin forms app and I want the context menu to open when I long click on map. I implemented click and long click events on map but i don't know to open context menu on maps. Is there a way to do this? 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very common problem with Maps

You need to use **TapGestureRecognizer** and froward all touch events to that handler.

I hope it will work.

```
<StackLayout x:Name="ConnectSP"  BackgroundColor ="Gray" HeightRequest="160" 
WidthRequest="125" Orientation="Vertical"> 
                 <Your_Map_Here></Your_Map_Here>
   <StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
       <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="OnConnectTapped"/>
   </StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
            </StackLayout>
```

Comment: Thank you but not working. TapGestureRecognizer is work when there is an object such as image, label. But it doesn't work if there is a map in it.